# Java global Variable access

Tags: java

I have a class say ABC and I want to have a global array that can be accessed by every function of the class, but the problem is that at compile time I do not know the size of the array, so I am dynamically allocating the global variable in the constructor, but then it is not accessible through other functions. Any suggestions how can I resolve this?

Comment: you are confused, Java does not have `global` variables, much less ones that are allocated in constructors. also modern Java never uses raw arrays

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: You can have the array as the `static` member of the class

Answer (score 4):

Use ArrayList instead Simple as that :)

EDIT : `public static ArrayList constant;`  can do wonders !

EDIT Again : Have a look at this question. It can answer your queries [Generic type for Arraylist of Arraylists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497346/generic-type-for-arraylist-of-arraylists)

Comment: Thanks, but for 2D arrays?? Actually I am new to java and don't know much about it.

Comment: When you say 2D does it mean the number of columns in this case is fixed ?? If yes make use of Javabean instead. And then use `ArrayList<BeanClassName>`

Comment: none of them, i.e neither row nor col is fixed.

Comment: In that case you can use ArrayList of ArrayList   'List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();'

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways :

1- Declare Array outside your Constructor, to make it accessible from other Classes ,declare it as static

2- Declare Array outside your Constructor,have a public get method for it. If array is not initialized return null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any implementation of the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface.  They do not need a predetermined size.