# How to create ArrayList of ArrayLists so that it fits the programe to interface principle

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I know this question has already been aksed, but I am looking at it from a different perspective.
An answer is provided on what the [generic type for ArrayList of ArrayLists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497346/generic-type-for-arraylist-of-arraylists) is. However, I am looking for best practices and to program to interface. I then came up with the three options below.

Questions:

1. Why the option 1 is compilation error? Why the conversion cannot take place?
2. Which one of the options 2 or 3 are preferred and where?
3. In the option 3 why the interface "List" is appeared at the right hand side of the statement? Please provide an appropriate answer to this. I need to understand these nested generic definitions.

   ```
    1) List<List<Integer>> arList1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    2) List<ArrayList<Integer>> arList2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    3) List<List<Integer>> arList3 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This code:

   ```
   List<List<Integer>> arList1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
   ```

   is a compilation error because `List<List<Integer>>` can legally hold a `LinkedList<Integer>`, but the right-hand side of the assignment cannot. Generics are not covariant. (See the excellent [article on generics by Brian Goetz](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp01255/).)
2. I prefer 3 unless I want to explicitly require that the lists added to `arList2` must be instances of `ArrayList`. While such a requirement would be quite rare, it can arise.
3. In Java 7, you don't need to do this. You can write:

   ```
   List<List<Integer>> arList1 = new ArrayList<>();
   ```

   and the compiler will fill in `List<Integer>` as the generic type argument on the right side. With Java 6 and earlier, you need to explicitly provide a generic argument to the constructor call that is compatible with the generic argument of the left side of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is a compilation error because the types are not compatible. Indeed, you can put a `List` which is not an `ArrayList` into `List<List<Integer>>`, but not into `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`. That's why `List` appears on the right hand side in option 3.

The option 3 is preferred because it refers to objects by their interfaces. See Joshua Bloch, *Effective Java: Programming Language Guide*, item 34.